# PowerApps Gallery - Hybrid Screen

Tags: powerapps

I currently have a PowerApps app that is connected to a SQL Server database with information about books. I am trying to make a hybrid screen that displays a gallery of books. I cannot figure out how to make the price and book id display when one of the book records is selected.

Here is the book overview screen. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Really, we need more information about the Data source to give an accurate answer. Here is a guess and I can update if you supply more details of the SQL table and it's columns:

When a user clicks on a line in your gallery, you can set a variable of the selected record to be used in another UI element. So, click on the list row, override the `OnSelect` attribute to `Set()` a value of `ThisItem` (The selected Book) to a variable `varBook` (or whatever you want to call it):

[image]

Now, in your other text fields on the UI element you want to display details of the selected book, set the `Text` value to be the attributes of the record: `varBook.ID` and `varBook.price` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm understanding it wrong, you should just do **Select(Parent)** on OnSelect property of the gallery item. Display BookID and Price as **BookGallery.Selected.BookID** and **BookGallery.Selected.Price**.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please consider using the code formatting to format your code.